# How to restrict input to the defined size of an array through scanf?

Tags: arrays, string, overflow, scanf

How to limit the number of character input accepted to the array `size-1` with `scanf`? 
Like for char a[10], to only take 9 characters. 
Is it possible or not. And in which header file is `snprintf` defined? Is it compiler specific? Let me know the header file for it.

Answer (score 0):

> How to limit the number of character input accepted to the array
>   size-1 with scanf? Like for char a[10], to only take 9 characters. Is
>   it possible or not.

It's possible to specify a maximum field width, but it's probably not what you want. I'm going to derive my example from the `%s` format directive. Just place the width, in decimal digits, between the `%` and the `s`, for example `"%9s"` instructs scanf to read and copy no more than 9 characters. Keep in mind that `%s` instructs `scanf` to read a *word* of input, not necessarily a *line*. It'll stop copying input into your array as soon as it comes across a whitespace character.

```
char a[10];

/* TODO: Handle scanf errors */
assert(scanf("%9s", a) == 1);
```

> And in which header file is snprintf defined?

`<stdio.h>`.

> Is it compiler specific?

There are two types of C99 programming implementations. Freestanding implementations don't require `<stdio.h>`, so technically `snprintf` isn't required to exist in these environments. It's most likely that you're using a hosted implementation, however. Hosted implementations require `snprintf` in `<stdio.h>`.